# Programmatically build SQL queries in Java

Tags: library, java, sql, jdbc

We have a query that needs to be built dynamically when the user chooses search params in our GUI.

I understand how to do this by hand in SQL by appending strings.  While this does work there are a lot of edge cases in dynamically formatting SQL which are tedious and error prone.

I typically prefer to use Hibernate's criteria API for something like this because I can call add as many restrictions to the criteria as I need.  For example...

```
    // Filter based on the customer no if required
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerNo)) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("customerNo", customerNo));
    }
    // Filter based on the name if required
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(locationName)) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", locationName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    }
```

The problem is some tables do not map well to Hibernate for various reasons.  In order to use the Criteria API it appears I need my tables mapped nicely to entities.

Is there a technique/library anybody (in Java) is aware of to make dynamically building SQL less error prone than simple string smashing?  I have seen Slick for Scala but nothing for Java.

I have wondered if hibernate exposes some of its low-level code in the Dialects to build SQL programmatically.

Comment: How about [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) ("jOOQ generates Java code from your database and lets you build type safe SQL queries through its fluent API.")?